# Can two distinct elements have same inverse in a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know that every element in a group have unique inverse,i.e, an element cannot have two distinct inverses.

My question is that whether two distinct elements in a group can have common inverses, in other words , if the inverse of $x$ is $b$, then is it possible to have another element $y$ such that its inverse is $b$,as well ? If it is possible, then can you give me an example, if not how can i prove it ?

According to me, yes it is possible because $x$ has unique inverse $b$, and $y$ has unique inverse $b$. However, I am not sure.

Comment: What's your definition of "inverse"? ;-) And then what is the inverse of your "$b$"?

Comment: Ask yourself what the inverse of the inverse of $a$ is.

Comment: If $b$ is the inverse of both $x$ and $y$, then also $x$ and $y$ are both the inverse of $b$.

Comment: What should $xby$ be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(xb=e)\wedge (yb=e)\Longrightarrow$ $xb=yb\Longrightarrow x=y$, as the cancellation law holds in groups. So the answer is no.

Comment: So, as a result each element in a group can have only one inverse and every element have to have distinct inverses. No two element can have same inverse, right ?

Comment: What I showed is that the (unique) inverses of two distinct elements are distinct in turn. The uniqueness of the inverse of a given $x$ follows rather from $xb=xc\Longrightarrow b=c$, yet again by the cancellation law. Yes, no two elements can have etc.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Show that $$(g^{-1})^{-1}=g$$ for all elements $g$ of all groups.

> In other words, $(\cdot)^{-1}$ is a bijection on each group.

Comment: sorry but the other answer answered earlier and I can only accept one answer

Comment: So, as a result each element in a group can have only one inverse and every element have to have distinct inverses. No two element can have same inverse, right ?

Comment: That's okay, @harrypotter. It happens all the time. And yes.